# Using same RSA keys for every transmission?

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib

Suppose I wish to transmit data from the client (browser, js+ajax) to the server (PHP), using RSA encryption. Is it a good idea to define one large RSA key pair for the server and use it every time?

I'm bringing this question up because [`phpseclib`](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)'s key generator is very slow for acceptable (1024+) key sizes (tested on Core2Duo 3GHz 3GB RAM):

128bit - 86ms,
256bit - 528ms,
512bit - 2240ms averages.

So generating keys for each transmission is infeasible (or am I overlooking something?)

*(No need to recommend SSH, thank you)*

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding all the theory and focusing on performance.

Comment: @GregS Perhaps, but I'd still like to know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half the reason 1024+ key sizes are considered acceptable is because they *don't* need to be regenerated.

In SSH you have the server host key and that's just generated once - when the SSH server is installed. Then you have (optionally) keys that the client uses to login with and they're not regenerated every time either - just once and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Its common do create public/private key pair for each party once and use them to verify peers as well as using them to transmit secrets.

Using only rsa is uncommon so usually one create a symmetric chipher (e.g. AES) and use rsa to verify and transmit a random key before you do the rest in that chipher. Reason for that is that the length in bits of your message cannot be longer than the length of the key when using rsa and it's quite slow.

SSL, SSH, GPG and PGP all do it like that.

What's wrong with SSL?

Comment: Some shared hosts just don't allow SSL.

Comment: @Sylwester Nothing wrong with SSL, I just can't use it for this project. Thanks for your answer!